# Can we get mtg-autocard support for inside code blocks?

Tags: support, feature-request, mtg-autocard

Code blocks are often used on the site for the fixed-width indentation the provide. [This answer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/12653/1749) attempted to use a mtg-autocard link inside the code block, but it didn't link. Would it be possible to enable the autocard link inside code blocks? (Or is there already a way to do it?)

Comment: I'll look into it, but I'm not sure this is fixable. The main purpose of a code block aside from formatting is that it ignores all other formatting characters (which is also why `**bolding** and *italicizing*` don't work in a code block). I'm not sure if it's possible to make an exception, but I'll poke around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The workaround here is not to use code blocks for the indented list. If you use `&nbsp;` to force non-code-formatted text to indent, Markdown will not start the count over.

Here's an example. This text:

```
1. **Albert** casts [mtg:Ancestral Recall]. [mtg:Ancestral Recall] Goes onto the stack.  
&nbsp;&nbsp;2. **Albert** wants to do nothing and implicitly (by sitting there doing nothing) passes priority  
&nbsp;&nbsp;3. **Nancy** gains priority and responds with [mtg:Counterspell]   
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;4. **Nancy** gains priority and implicitly passes by doing nothing.  
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;5. **Albert gains priority** and, looking smug, says "In response" and slaps his own [mtg:Counterspell] onto the table. Poor **Nancy**!
```

looks like:

1. **Albert** casts [Ancestral Recall](http://www.wizards.com/magic/autocard.asp?name=Ancestral%20Recall). [Ancestral Recall](http://www.wizards.com/magic/autocard.asp?name=Ancestral%20Recall) Goes onto the stack.
     2. **Albert** wants to do nothing and implicitly (by sitting there doing nothing) passes priority
     3. **Nancy** gains priority and responds with [Counterspell](http://www.wizards.com/magic/autocard.asp?name=Counterspell)
       4. **Nancy** gains priority and implicitly passes by doing nothing.
       5. **Albert gains priority** and, looking smug, says "In response" and slaps his own [Counterspell](http://www.wizards.com/magic/autocard.asp?name=Counterspell) onto the table. Poor **Nancy**!

Comment: Thanks, Abby! I applied your formatting to the answer in question.

Answer (score 2):

I feel like that's a formatting issue: that stuff does need to be arranged hierarchically neatly, but it shouldn't be in a code block. It's just that the list auto-formatter (which resets numbering with indentation) is getting in the way of how Rawrgamming wants to show the stack using indentation for the separate levels.